# How do I create strike-through style text on Mac Evernote?

Tags: macos, evernote

I can create <del>strike-through</del> style text on Windows Evernote.

[image: Windows Evernote]

But cannot find the button on Mac version

[image]

Comment: "to strikethrough text, highlight the text then CMD-T. Click the strikethrough option at the top" I don't have a mac in front of me to test, which is why it isn't an "answer"

Comment: @Raystafarian It works. Post it as an answer. But why it does not show in the bar?

Comment: It's not an implemented shortcut yet :(

Comment: To prevent questions about justified alignment, which doesn't have a button either: It's in the menu, *Format » Alignment » Justify*

Comment: heh, none of the answers here work in Yosemite 10.10.5. You can do the format menu -> styles -> struck through but select, apply and done don't do anything, nor do they add them to the favorites. WTF

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<s>To <del>strike-through</del> text, highlight the text then <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and click the *strikethrough* option at the top</s>

**2015 update**: right-click > Format > Strikethrough

[2015 KB Article](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#/article/23168732) still shows no *keyboard shortcut*.

---

#### Shortcut Now Documented in Knowledge Base

***2015 update r2***: The first update back in April of this year noted *the [2015 KB Article](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#/article/23168732)* still showed no *keyboard shortcut* for strikethrough.

As of today (and maybe before today, I haven't checked) - it *does* show the keyboard shortcut -

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

for strike through, matching the other answers *officially*.

[image]

Answer (score 39):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works for me in V3.3.1 but wasn't sure when this was added.

Comment: This is indeed much faster that the chosen answer.

Comment: lifesaver! Now only if one could set their prefered shortcut for it..

Comment: Where did you find this information?  It works for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize as of Evernote v6:

**[The accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/388433/139307) no longer works**, because the floating `Fonts` window (invoked with <kbd>⌘T</kbd> or `Format > Show Fonts`) in recent Evernote versions does NOT show the underline and strikethrough options anymore.

The **keyboard shortcut** noted in other answers **still works**, however: <kbd>⌃⌘K</kbd>

Overview of **options for accessing text-styling functionality**:

- [*doesn't show ALL styles, notably not strikethrough*] **toolbar** at the top of a note
- **shortcut menu** for selected text: `Format > ...`
- **menu**: `Format > Style > ...`
- **keyboard shortcuts**: see menu; as of Evernote 6.0:

[image: test-styling kebyboard shortcuts]

Answer (score 2):

I believe <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> still works even with the version `5.6.1`. If it does not there are at least two possibilities:

1. It conflicts with some other shortcut. Go to Evernote Preferences <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and choose the Shortcuts tab. In my case it was conflicting with Quick Note, so I changed it to something else.
2. Evernote changed the combination. Go to "Format > Styles" in the mac menu and check the up-to-date combination as pointed out in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

v5.5.2:

Hover on top Mac menus and go to Format > Styles. All the shortcuts are listed. Even if they change, you can always look them up this way.